# .htaccess redirect for parent but not children?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a number of URLs that I need to redirect to new locations, but there are some situations where child pages need to remain active and not redirected. For example:

`/products` would redirect to `http://www.newsite.com/products`

`/products/category1` would redirect to `http://www.newsite/products/category1`

**But** `/products/specialitem` would not get redirected at all.

Is this possible with either Redirect or RedirectMatch?

Doing a `Redirect 301 /products http://www.newsite.com/products` seems to affect all child pages

Thanks for any guidance!

**Edit:**

Using waynethec's answer, I was able to get started. But can anyone clarify why my first rule below works but the others do not?

`RedirectMatch 301 ^segment-one$ http://www.google.com/`

`RedirectMatch 301 ^segment-one/segment-two$ http://news.google.com/`

`RedirectMatch 301 ^segment-one/segment-two/segment-three$ http://cnn.com/`

`RedirectMatch 301 ^segment-one/segment-two/segment-three/foobar$ http://gbv.com/`

(By not working, I mean that I still can get to the pages, rather than them getting redirected.)

Comment: Welcome to the world of `mod_rewrite` )) Of course, you can do that with RedirectMatch, but if number of requirements increase - switch to RewriteRules.. `RedirectMatch 301 ^/products(?!/specialitem) http://www.newsite.com/products` Did not check it though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use the following RedirectMatch rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/products$ http://www.newsite.com/products
```

Note that this will only redirect requests for /products, not /products/, or /products/pagename.extension.

Comment: This is really helpful, but what if I have more segments in my URL? For example:

`/category1/subcat1` redirects to `http://newsite.com/products`

`/category1/subcat1/product1/details/` redirects to `http://newsite.com/products/somepage`
`/category1/subcat1/product2/details2/` redirects to `http://newsite.com/products/somepage2`

`/category1/subcat2/foo/bar/` redirects to `http://newsite.com/products/lorem/ipsum`

Comment: Maybe this better asks my follow-up question: Why does the first rule below work for me, but the subsequent ones do not?

`RedirectMatch 301 ^segment-one$ http://www.google.com/`
`RedirectMatch 301 ^segment-one/segment-two$ http://news.google.com/`
`RedirectMatch 301 ^segment-one/segment-two/segment-three$ http://cnn.com/`
`RedirectMatch 301 ^segment-one/segment-two/segment-three/foobar$ http://gbv.com/`

Comment: The syntax you've provided is valid and should work as you expect it to. Do you have any other rules in .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/products(?!/specialitem)(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/products$1
```

This will redirect `/products`, or anything after it, except `/products/specialitem/`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add conditions, this also worked for me. Note, I had to eliminate the slash between `^` and `products` when using RewriteRule.

```
RewriteCond [...whatever your conditions are...]

# test with 302 first to avoid annoying caching issues
# RewriteRule ^products$  http://www.newsite.com/products [R=302,NC,L]

# but use 301 in production once you know it's working
RewriteRule ^products$  http://www.newsite.com/products [R=301,NC,L]
```